# Store multidimensional array in modifier with MaxScript

Tags: multidimensional-array, parameters, modifier, maxscript

Is there a way to store a multidimensional array as a parameter of a simplemod modifier created with MaxScript? I can't find a way in the maxscript help.

Answer (score 2):

Maxscript help in the FAQ section says:

MAXScript FAQ > How do I create a multi-dimensional array?

A MAXScript Array is a one-dimensional list of elements. An element of an array is addressed by its index in brackets,

FOR EXAMPLE

```
myArray = #(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)

myArray[5] --> will return 50, the fifth element of the array.
```

Since an array can be an element inside of another array, you can create multi-dimensional arrays as you desire by placing multiple arrays inside an array. Using an index in brackets, you can reference the sub-array, using another pair of brackets and an index you can access an element inside the sub-array,

FOR EXAMPLE

```
-- create an array with two elements, each one an array with 10 elements.

myMultiDimArray=#(#(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),#(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))

-- add a third element to the array containing 10 more elements

append myMultiDimArray #(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000)

myMultiDimArray[2][5] --> returns 50 - the 5th element of the 2nd sub-array
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Is #floatTab what you are looking for?

Also check out http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php?t-1201389.html